# Taking a drone inside the Louvre?

Tags: paris, the-louvre, drones

I've been to the Louvre twice and every time I'm there there's a large crowd in front of the Mona Lisa.

I think what'd be really cool is to photograph the crowd aerially. Like I go into that room, pull the drone out of my backpack and just let it fly up to the ceiling and take a picture or video or whatever.

My question is...  is that doable? Would I get in trouble if I did that?

Comment: Indoor use of a drone in an art museum?  I'm pretty sure, for liability reasons, that that would be highly frowned upon.

Comment: Seriously? A drone, indoor, in a museum??

Comment: With some of the most valuable and easily damaged art in the world?

Comment: Obviously you can't do this :)  And just a small point, looking at "the Mona Lisa" on a small crappy TV screen ..  just stay at home and watch a documentary on it.

Comment: I wonder if it's actually fair to downvote this question?  I mean even if the answer is firm, it's a perfectly good question.

Comment: Why wouldn't you just contact the Louvre and ask? There are security guards in the room with the Mona Lisa, so they'd certainly be able to stop you if you don't have permission.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

First of all, no backpacks allowed, no bags big enough to bring anything worth the effort.

Secondly, all bags going into any Paris museum are scanned and/or looked through, basically for bombs but a drone might stand out enough for the searcher to take note.

Thirdly, there are guards all through the museum and they will take action, and with Paris on high alerts, I guess police will be involved, even if you just try to outsmart the crowds.

Fourthly, with all art which is potentially in danger from your drone, I think you will see a high bill if they feel they can make it stick.

(Side note)
Most museums state these days that selfie sticks are not allowed. And those are easy to control compared to drones.